# Qt client - connect to C server

Tags: c++, c, qt, qtgui, qtnetwork

I'm trying to create a client that should connect to a C server. I must use TCP. I already have a server which is fully functional, but I'm unable to connect my client. I don't want to send any data to server (at this point). I just want to establish a connection and open up a new dialog box.

Here is the code in Void Login::on_pushButton_clicked() slot. // pushButon is my login button

```
pSocket = new QTcpSocket (this);
connect (pSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), SLOT(waitNextStep()));
pSocket->connectToHost(ui->lineEdit->text(), ui->lineEdit_2->text().toInt());
if(pSocket->waitForConnected())
{
    Menu mMenu;
    mMenu.setModal(true);
    mMenu.exec();
}
else
{
    QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Error"),tr("Error at Connect"));
}
```

I already defined the Menu class and I know it's functional since I tested it without the connection part. The IP fetching part from the lineEdits is also functional. The pSocket is declared in the Login class, as a private member (QTcpSocket *pSocket;).

Unfortunatelly I'm new to QT and I don't really know what the 'waitNextStep()' function should containt. I just did a return 1; I am unsure about the SLOT in the connect function since I noticed in many examples that there were different functions there.

If I run the program I get no errors and the program executes just fine. But when I hit the login button, the dialog box freezes for ~15 seconds - it's unresponsive. After that, I get the 'Error at connect' message. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: "Unfortunatelly I'm new to QT and I don't really know what the 'waitNextStep()' function should containt." -> Well, that is not a Qt question. It is a use case question which _you_ need to know.

Comment: I know that I have a lot of things to learn, but this is an urgent project so I'm just getting as much information as I can from tutorials and examples. I can't read and absorb the documentation right now. Thanks for the reply anyway

Comment: Sounds like the usual project management problem people easily fall into: "get it done, get it done, do not estimate how much work it needs." Either way, I was not judging your Qt skills, but saying the fact that we do not know the use case thoroughly enough, and hence what exactly should be done in that method, so we can only give general hints without further clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunatelly I'm new to QT and I don't really know what the 'waitNextStep()' function should containt. I just did a return 1; I am unsure about the SLOT in the connect function since I noticed in many examples that there were different functions there.

It highly depends on your use case, but that is usually the handler of the incoming data whatever you wish to do with it, potentially including that you just store it in a member variable for the moment.

> If I run the program I get no errors and the program executes just fine. But when I hit the login button, the dialog box freezes for ~15 seconds - it's unresponsive. After that, I get the 'Error at connect' message. Any help will be much appreciated.

It is because `if(pSocket->waitForConnected())` is the blocking (i.e. sync) usage of the asynchronous Qt operation. What I would suggest to do instead is to connect to the connected signal as per [documentation](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qabstractsocket.html#connected):

> void QAbstractSocket::connected() [signal]
>
> This signal is emitted after connectToHost() has been called and a connection has been successfully established.
>
> Note: On some operating systems the connected() signal may be directly emitted from the connectToHost() call for connections to the localhost.

Comment: Look, I simply can't make it work. You need to be a bit more specific on what should I do. I modified the code several times and tried to use the connected signal, but not a chance... Thanks in advance

Comment: @KupiKupi: this is not a home-work site, especially without clear use cases, errors faced, et al, I am afraid. Try to explain to that your managers urging you will not help anyone in this situation. It will cause more harm than help.

Comment: The only possible harm in this situation is not to get the project done in time. And it has nothing to do with my job. 'What I would suggest to do instead is to connect to the connected signal as per documentation:'. As per documentation, there's no explanation on how to do that

Comment: @KupiKupi: you _need_ to have a minimal understanding on this site. Pressuring people writing working code for you is off-topic AFAICT. You _are_ supposed to show some effort. I will not be a free home-work writer for such a badly managed project, I am afraid, nor is it the purpose of the site in my understanding. I am happy to help people who are willing to learn for the fun of it themselves after reading docs and gainining some minimal understanding.

Comment: But I've read docs. And I don't think it's so badly managed. Try to be me for a second. Having a lot of pressure on your shoulders makes learning difficult. I didn't had weeks to complete this project. Just 1 week. And I still have 2 days. I can't see fun in this situation. It's your decision anyway, but I didn't asked you to write code. Just to be a bit more specific.

Comment: It is the basic connect call similarly to which you already have in your code as well. It makes me think that the code was copy/pasted without understanding it, so: connect (pSocket, SIGNAL(connected()), SLOT(handleConnected())); and connect (pSocket, SIGNAL(error()), SLOT(handleError()));

Comment: After a bit more digging I got to a conclusion. My handdleConnected will get called as soon as the connection establishes. I deleted  the If part. In the handleConnected function i wrote the necessary code in order to open my next dialog box. Now the program doesn't freeze. However, it does nothing when I press on login